# How can i hide the menu item 'PARTS' in powerbuilder?

Tags: tags, powerbuilder

How can i hide menu item that having a tag of PARTS?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a public function on the menu class (in my app: m_main) without return value.

```
mf_HideByTag(string as_tag) >>>

// Hide each menu item having Tag = <as_tag>
long i
for i = 1 to UpperBound(Item)
   if Item[i].Tag = as_tag then Hide(Item[i])
next
```

Call this function from anywhere like:

```
m_main.mf_HideByTag('PARTS')
```

NOTE: This function does no recursive search through the drop down menus. It only parses the immediate menu bar items.

Comment: From PB Help regarding Hide of Menus:  You cannot use Hide to hide a drop-down or cascading menu or any menu that has an MDI frame window as its parent window. Nor can you hide a window that has been opened as an MDI sheet.

Comment: I believe that piece of PB Help is slightly outdated.Just tested my code fragment running PB 12.5.1 in an MDI Frame using an extra test menu item in the Help dropdown. The code hides the tag marked dropdown.
Run #1: Click Menu>Test as first menu item => Tag marked dropdown disappears.
Run #2: First click the tag marked drop down to ensure it is "alive"; then click Menu>Test => Tag marked dropdown still disappears.

Answer (score 0):

IF this is standard behavior for your application you might want to put this functionality in the window ancestor.

You can get a reference to the menu via the MenuID property of the window.  You can then loop through the menu items and set the visible property to false for those with the appropriate Tag value.

You could perform this in the open event of the window.